# AS3 TextField autoscroll to the bottom

Tags: actionscript-3, scroll, textfield

How to autoscroll to the bottom of the TextField in ActionScript while adding text there programmatically:

```
var _output:TextField = new TextField();
for (var i:int = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    _output.appendText("Hello World!");
}
```

Also consider that the vertical scrolling of the TextField should be enabled, and once a new text was added then autoscroll to the bottom should be executed again.

Comment: Note that you are assigning "Hello World!" to `_output.text` a hundred times in a row. You should call `appendText()` instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should listen for `Event.CHANGE` event on the TextField in question. [Event description relative to textField](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#event%3achange) And if you capture this event, you play with  `scrollV` property. Say, like this:

```
_output.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,scrollAllDown);
function scrollAllDown(e:Event):void {
    var tf:TextField=(e.target as TextField);
    if (!tf) return; 
    tf.scrollV=tf.maxScrollV;
}
```

Update: Catching `Event.CHANGE` does not work, I leave this in case someone stumbles on this method and too finds out it doesn't work. So, the only way is to subclass the `TextField` and manually override `appendText()` method to include scrolling, like this:

```
public class OutputTF extends TextField 
{ 
    // constructor omitted
    override public function appendText(text:String):void 
    { super.appendText(text); this.scrollV=this.maxScrollV; } 
}
```

Comment: Why you get the `e.target as TextField`? Instead couldn't you use `_output` considering that actually it is a static member of a class?

Comment: Well, let's say you need more tha a single textField to autoscroll - then you will have two lines of `addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,scrollAllDown)` to two different TextFields, and to determine *which* TextField has dispatched the event, you will need to process `e.target`.

Comment: This does not work: `appendText` does not dispatch `Event.CHANGE` when text is changed **programmatically**.

Comment: Okay, going to research a method. It doesn't seem to be this easy. I actually thought this functionality is embedded. Perhaps you then should override `appendText()` function in a subclass of `TextField` to dispatch this event manually, or directly do an autoscroll. `public class OutputTF extends TextField { ... override public function appendText(text:String):void { super.appendText(text); this.scrollV=this.maxScrollV; } ... }`

Comment: Right, please write this in your answer so I could accept it.

Comment: You could also manually dispatch CHANGE from the code that appends the text.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship Indeed, the trick is that it's better to have this functional encapsulated into a class, so that you won't have to write more event dispatching lines in case of this TextField be a multipurpose logger, thus its text might be updated from numerous parts of code. A listener extends functionality to a certain degree, but it appears that its anchor is not implemented in the base class.

Comment: You could encapsulate the logging in a parent container, such as a Sprite subclass. Not sure why it's so important to do it by subclassing TextField only.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship The purpose of a logger is to store and display the text, for this `TextField` is the best candidate. If you'll be extending `Sprite`, you'll still have to have a `TextField` in there, this kinda breaks the purpose of extending `Sprite`. Moreover, if you'd publish your embedded `TextField`, or publish all its properties to allow customization, which is done for you if you extend `TextField`. `Sprite` is an instrument with a completely different purpose, and using it as a base for logger is like using a microscope as base for a hammer.

Comment: TextField isn't intended to be a logger either, so it's kind of 6 of one half dozen of the other. The point of using Sprite is that you then have one piece of code that is able to write to the TextField (and call its CHANGE event manually or even dispatch its own custom event that speaks more to the purpose of the logging). I think the whole reason for this thread is that Macromedia never intended for TextField to be extended.

Comment: And if you want to get into good OO design, it's probably not a good idea to have multiple parts of the code writing to the logger anyway. Instead, it's probably better to have a data object of some kind with log messages and then have a controller of some sort update the TextField with the text as that data object changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the scrollV and maxScrollV properties of TextField:

```
var _output:TextField = new TextField();
for (var i:int = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    _output.appendText("Hello World!");
    //set vertical scroll position to max value
    _output.scrollV = _output.maxScrollV;
}
```