# Tracking all events that an object ever dispatches

Tags: actionscript-3, events

I want to find out if an object that implements `IEventDispatcher` actually dispatches anything. I cannot listen on every kind of events possible, also it seems that I cannot override `dispatchEvent()` method in a subclass to track underlying functionality of an object - the events are being dispatched, the listeners get triggered, yet the overriding method isn't called. So, how can I find out if an **unknown** event has been dispatched, and at least get its type? The particular object in question is `TextField`, as I want to track attempts to change its text by ANY available method, and react on a change. [The question where this originated.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18206187/as3-textfield-autoscroll-to-the-bottom)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you _can_ override dispatchEvent, but without looking at your code it is hard to say what is going wrong.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship I did exactly that, `override public function dispatchEvent(event:Event):Boolean { trace(event.type); return super.dispatchEvent(event); }` and instantiated a subclass, and the overridden function just doesn't get called. I mean I need to watch for events fired *by* an instance, not a particular question of tracing text property.

Comment: Did you do this in Flash pro, Builder, where? And are you sure the subclass was actually used? For example, you couldn't actually create a subclass of TextField on the stage--you'd have to instantiate through code. Is this for any InteractiveObject, or does it only happen on TextField subclasses?

Comment: @AmyBlankenship FlashDevelop, thus no stage and full control of what do I instantiate. So yes, the subclass was used. I didn't check for other interactive objects yet, but I need an object that's dispatching events. A Loader could do, maybe, as it dispatches quite a set of events.

Answer (score 0):

TextField being a [documented class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#event%3achange), you actually have a list of all the events it could ever dispatch so you could listen to all of them (I can't give more info regarding overriding dispatchEvent, imho it should work but I have never tested it).

However, if you just want to track changes of the text, I can see two solutions that should work:

- If you can override the TextField class and instantiate it instead, then you could override the text setter: `override public function set text(text:String):void`.
- Another solution would be to put an event listener on `Event.ENTER_FRAME` and check there if the text property of the TextField has changed. This is more brutal, but will work in cases where you don't create the TextField yourself.

Comment: I have tested overriding dispatchEvent, and it didn't work. About subclassing TextField - yes I can do this, I just want an universal solution that should work on every `IEventDispatcher` there is. A negative answer with a proper explanation will also do.