# In ActionScript 3.0 how to add dynamically text in textArea?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

[image]I have to display all the text based on the actions done within my game. I have to add the text below the current text, but how would I move all of the previous text upwards so each time it adds a new text it will place it in the same spot and only move the previous text, as shown in the image.

how to generate a text dynamically one by one based on the game actions performed in flash?

Comment: "as shown in the image": where is the image?

Comment: show as an example...

Comment: May be you just need to scroll the textarea to the bottom: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18206187/as3-textfield-autoscroll-to-the-bottom

Answer (score 1):

No. 
You just need to use **List** from **Components/ User Interface**, this makes what you need.

here you have some examples:
**1
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_UsingComponentsAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7fa6.html

**2
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-introduction-flash-list-and-tilelist-components--active-6593

Comment: Thanks :) It is working.But onclick the list should show as a popup window and again onclick it has to hide popup window..

Comment: Shoud popup when you click what object?

Comment: when i click button that list object should popup

Comment: you can make a tween. And when you click on button, just play that tween (popup the list), and when you click again you will reverse that tween.

Comment: In whitch IDE do you code? If you code in Flash Profesional, then you can create tween for componenet directlly from timeline, else you would have to use Tween class...